# GSL-Shell: Can I add precompiled libraries designed to extend Lua?

Tags: windows, dll, lua, gsl

Can GSL-Shell use third party libraries designed to extend Lua/LuaJIT on windows? e.g.

```
http://luaforge.net/projects/vclua/
http://luaforge.net/projects/iup/
http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/
```

Like many "(windows) users" I do not want to invest time in learning to compile source code.

This makes Lua very attractive - a very stable core with "add-ons" in the form of pre-compiled DLLs. I had hoped that simply finding compiled DLLs and placing them in the cpath would allow me to "add batteries" and expand Lua to suit my needs.

However, it appears that these libraries may contain links to other supporting DLLs (unfortunately including lua51.dll and lua.5.1.dll - DLL HELL http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-11/msg01025.html).

GSL_Shell adds significant functionality to Lua; with routines for scientific computation and reading CSV files. http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/

I could not find documentation for GSL-Shell explaining which Lua libraries had been compiled in to the executable. Nor could I figure out if it possible to use the libgsl-0.dll as an add-on for a standard Lua installation.

The added functionality of GSL-Shell is very attractive and I would like to learn how to use this software, before investing the time I would like to know if the environment is extendable?

Many Thanks

Kind Regards

Comment: gslshell makes use of `ffi` that comes with luajit and that's how it's able to communicate with `libgsl-0.dll` without separate bindings. `libgsl-0.dll` itself *is not* a lua module -- it's just a regular windows dll. Standard lua won't be able to use that without some external help.

Comment: Also might want to look at [this github issue](https://github.com/franko/gsl-shell/issues/1), I think that addresses what you're asking.

Comment: I posteda similar question at github francesco replied: https://github.com/franko/gsl-shell/issues/12 
Talking about your question: right now I cannot ensure that gsl shell is binary compatible with luajit. The good news if that I became aware of this need from many users and the next release (2.3.1) will be binary compatible.

The strength of gsl shell is that it is based on a sound programming language, Lua, with an outstanding JIT compiler, LuaJIT2. I'm also trying to ensure a good quality of the gsl shell modules and their documentation.

Francesco